# Catastrophic error happen

Tags: sharepoint-server

The site collection cannot create a team site. It says "catastrophic error"log tells nothing. Window viewer also gives no clue. I am wondering if any one has any solution. We have tried all the possible options. We are not able to fix it and we are forced to migrate the site to another site collection which comes with a lot of politics. Does anyone has any advise?

FYI other templates work fine except team site

Comment: It can happen because of a number of reasons (probably data integrity related). Can you check SP logs for more information?

Comment: possibly someone modified the template files on the local server(s)?